# Refer to closed-generic type without explicitly declaring subclass (extending base type)

Tags: generics, typescript

Is it possible to refer to generic type with specified generic parameter without previously declaring the subclass?
I don't know how to describe it so here's the code:

```
registerView(CarView); // I can do this
registerView(View<Car>); // ... but I can't this. any way to avoid declaring CarView-like subclass?

class View<T> { }
class CarView extends View<Car> { }
class Car { }

function registerView(v: Object){ }
```

*Note* I come from C# background, among others. Here's what I'd do with C#

```
class View<T> {}
class Car {}
class CarView: View<Car>{}

void Main()
{
    registerView(typeof(CarView));
    registerView(typeof(View<Car>));
}
void registerView(Type t){}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it doesn't work this way in TypeScript because the generated JavaScript doesn't have the generic information. You can pass in the class name on its own: `registerView(View);`

Comment: @DavidSherret please mak it an answer so I can accept it! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this probably doesn't work because generics won't be in the compiled JavaScript so there would be no difference at runtime between statements like `registerView(View<Car>)` or `registerView(View<string>)` and so the compiler is probably just warning you about that.

Due to this, you might as well just pass in `registerView(View)`.

On a sidenote, in this scenario you probably want to change your function to handle the generic parameter. Here's an example of a function that creates a new view from the `typeof View`—the class.

```
class View<T> { }
class Car { }

function createView<T>(view: typeof View){ return new view<T>(); }

var v = createView<Car>(View); // v is typed as View<Car>
```